# Insert a record in custom object on User Logout

Tags: logout

I want to insert a record in custom object whenever a user logout from the salesforce.
Is there any thing available to track this and create a record as soon as user logouts?

Comment: I doubt you could achieve this. Salesforce has EventLogFile object https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm available to monitor such events. However, this information is available only 24 hrs after the event takes place.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possible event based approach as far as I know.
The closest thing I can think of is [this](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_login_logout_lines.htm).

```
SELECT Id,EventType,LogFile,LogDate,LogFileLength
FROM EventLogFile WHERE EventType='Logout'
```

**Trial:**

I tried to put a afterInsert Trigger on **EventLogFile** like below:

```
if(eventLogFile.EventType == 'Logout')
    // Create new record
```

But it will raise an error:

> SObject type does not allow triggers: EventLogFile

**Solution:**

Instead poll on a scheduled frequency for the **EventLogFile** for Logout EventType through REST API and create the custom records. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) document might help you implement the same